# Tapestry issues during migration from Websphere 8 to JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: migration, websphere-8, jboss6.x

CONTEXT :

I'm having my first internship as an engineer and my mission is to migrate an app from Websphere to JBoss. My approach was to place the .ear of the app in a the deployments file of a JBoss environment and then pick up the errors one by one.

ISSUE :

The application deploys (I get the .deployed file), however I have trouble accessing the GUI of the app. I get the following error when I try to access it on my browser :

"JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available."

I used the "tail-f" command to monitor the JBoss log and I get the following message when I try to access the GUI on my browser :

> 2018-09-26 10:01:02,456 DEBUG [org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry]
>   (http-10.221.250.223:11500-1) [  2] --> Invoking constructor
>   org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestGlobalsImpl() (at
>   RequestGlobalsImpl.java:30) via
>   org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at
>   TapestryModule.java:308) (for service 'RequestGlobals')
>
> 2018-09-26 10:01:02,457 DEBUG
>   [org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.RequestGlobals]
>   (http-10.221.250.223:11500-1) Invoking constructor
>   org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestGlobalsImpl() (at
>   RequestGlobalsImpl.java:30) via
>   org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at
>   TapestryModule.java:308) (for service 'RequestGlobals')
>
> 2018-09-26 10:01:02,457 DEBUG [org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry]
>   (http-10.221.250.223:11500-1) [  2] <-- Invoking constructor
>   org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestGlobalsImpl() (at
>   RequestGlobalsImpl.java:30) via
>   org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.bind(ServiceBinder) (at
>   TapestryModule.java:308) (for service 'RequestGlobals') [0.43 ms]
>
> 2018-09-26 10:01:02,458 DEBUG [org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry]
>   (http-10.221.250.223:11500-1) [  1] --> Instantiating service
>   ThreadLocale implementation via
>   org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.ThreadLocaleImpl() (at
>   ThreadLocaleImpl.java:24) via
>   org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder)
>   (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49)
>   2018-09-26 10:01:02,459 DEBUG
>   [org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.ThreadLocale]
>   (http-10.221.250.223:11500-1) Invoking constructor
>   org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.ThreadLocaleImpl() (at
>   ThreadLocaleImpl.java:24) via
>   org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder)
>   (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) (for service 'ThreadLocale')
>
> 2018-09-26 10:01:02,459 DEBUG [org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry]
>   (http-10.221.250.223:11500-1) [  2] <-- Invoking constructor
>   org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.ThreadLocaleImpl() (at
>   ThreadLocaleImpl.java:24) via
>   org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.TapestryIOCModule.bind(ServiceBinder)
>   (at TapestryIOCModule.java:49) (for service 'ThreadLocale') [0.46 ms]

Which makes me think that the issue has to do with Tapestry.

So I went to see the Tapestry configuration in web.xml file and found this line which I think is problematic : com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFiltersCompatibility

As this seems to be a specific implementation of IBM Websphere.

Do you think that's the problem, or do you think that's something else ? Do you have an idea about the solution ?

Please, if you need more information, don't hesitate.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know Tapestry is not supported since EAP 5 !!!

Comment: @PanagiotisChavariotis Do you have an idea about how to solve this migration issue ?